# What Photoshop action icon has a small square overlaid on the bottom left of a document surrounded on the top-left by a right angle?

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-cs6

I downloaded a psd file and I found an action which I don't know to do it.

[image]

Comment: First, explain to those who may never have seen a "psd" file what application runs it. Second,  execute your questioned action and tell us what it does to an image.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft if you wanna see in the title (Photoshop), there is the name of the application which runs it, and if I could know the answer from your second request I couldn't write this question here. I

Answer (score 6):

It should be a clipping mask. Holding 'alt' and clicking on the bottom border of the layer should remove the mask. Or simply right click and search for something called 'clipping mask', 'remove clipping mask',...

If my answer is not engough: [Adobe Photoshop - Clipping masks](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/revealing-layers-clipping-masks.html)

Comment: What an exciting moment for me, this is my first answer ever :-D

Answer (score 0):

The symbol you're talking about is actually the "Smart Object" tool. To get it, you simply right-click on the layer and click "Convert to Smart Object."